# Bluetooth headphones do not show up in Recording devices in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, recording

I have a BeatsStudio Wireless headset and I'm running windows 10.

I can successfully connect the headphones to windows, and use it as a playback device.  [and use it as a playback device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfI04.png)

I can not use the build-in microphone, [as it does not show up in playback devices.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukSSF.png)

I have the latest drivers for the headset.

Comment: I have the same issue trying to use a Logitech H600; connecting it via my builtin bluetooth rather than the dongle it comes with. It shoes up as a playback device, but not as a recording device. In the device properties, it says the headset is connected, but the services only have "Audio Sink" and "Remote Control"

Comment: @djsumdog i'm here too for the h600. did you ever solve this?